# Banshee does not start (Ubuntu 12.04)

Tags: 12.04, banshee

I have installed banshee, but during the installation something went wrong and now i am experiencing this:

```
balg@scorpion:~$ banshee

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusServiceManager' from assembly 'Banshee.Services, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusServiceManager' from assembly 'Banshee.Services, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I have tried to remove and purge banshee, delete the config files and then reinstall it, but it didn't help. Can anyone help me?

Thanks,
balg

Comment: If you run `banshee --debug` from Terminal, it will provide more output that may help solve the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately i don't get more info with the --debug switch:

balg@scorpion:~$ banshee --debug
** Running Mono with --debug   **

Unhandled Exception: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusServiceManager' from assembly 'Banshee.Services, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Banshee.ServiceStack.DBusServiceManager' from assembly 'Banshee.Services, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Try logging in as a guest and running Banshee -- that will conclusively rule out anything related to config files in your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced some non-starting incidents.
You could try removing all the configuration stuff, which is stored in the folders /home/youruser/.config/banshee-1, /home/youruser/.gconf/apps/banshee-1

Once I removed them, banshee started without problems. 
However, I had to configure again some plugins like lastfm.

Comment: That's also where Banshee keeps its database of play counts, ratings, and playlists, so you might want to make a backup rather than removing it completely.

Comment: Thank you for the advice but i already tried that and that didn't help. :(